# How to setup AI in springboot kotlin poject

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, djl

> I want to use Deep learning java lib in my project. But I am not able
> to setup AI DJL in my spring boot kotlin  Gradle based project. I Use
> Buildgradle.kts , but I don't know how to add ai.djl in
> buildgradle.kts.

Answer (score 0):

DJL provides springboot starter package, you can add the following section in your build.gradle.kts:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("ai.djl.spring:djl-spring-boot-starter-pytorch-auto:0.11")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude(group = "org.junit.vintage", module = "junit-vintage-engine")
    }
    // See: https://github.com/awslabs/djl/blob/master/mxnet/mxnet-engine/README.md for MXNet library selection
}
```

You can find DJL springboot starter demo project from github: https://github.com/deepjavalibrary/djl-spring-boot-starter-demo